# Flutter scaffold extendbody not scrolling

Tags: flutter, floating-action-button, flutter-bottomnavigation

I am using notched FAB icon in bottom navigation bar and to make the notch transparent added extendbody in scaffold.

```
return Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: false,
        extendBody: true,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
```

[image]

after adding extendbody properties page content not scrolling to the end, some content on page falling behind the bottom navigation bar and not scrolling.

Please help me guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this widget to the end of the widget tree

```
SizedBox(
  height: kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
)
```

or add padding to the page

```
padding:EdgeInsets.only(bottom: kBottomNavigationBarHeight)
```